# Is there a manual for the run command in crashlytics framework

Tags: ios, crashlytics

`../Crashlytics/Crashlytics.framework/run <key>`

is there any parameter which can be used along with key which prints any success or the activities which happens when the run phase of the build gets executed. I was not able to find any documentation on this. ic you can point me any docs link for run command will be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The run command by default is printing out some information already. Specifically, it is printing out the version number of the framework the date/time and it provides a status of the dsym upload.  Here is example of what is printing out.

```
    [exec] 2014-07-02 16:44:27.146 run[62614:507] Crashlytics.framework/run 1.3.8
    [exec] 2014-07-02 16:44:30.025 run[62614:507] 
    [exec] 
    [exec] Crashlytics: AppName.app.dSYM uploaded statusCode 201
```

This is the output from my hudson job, but if you are doing this directly within xcode this will also be in your build logs (not the debug logs).  View them in Xcode by going to View/Navigators-->Report Navigators.  You will see the log entries for crashlytics in you latest build log.  The line that stararts with *crashlytics:* is the status.

I am not aware of any other switches for the crashlytics run application.

Comment: It's sad my teamcity is not showing "Crashlytics: AppName.app.dSYM uploaded statusCode 201" at all. It just shows Crashlytics.framework/run 1.3.11 and nothing more. Build is successfully created but dsym is not loaded and I can't get any info or log about what happened...

Comment: @Centurion: Did you find any help?

Comment: @BaSha I'v switched to Fabric (which contains latest version of Crashlytics) and managed to get it working using suggestions from here: https://github.com/zergtmn/Fabric/issues/5#issuecomment-86419299 (see my question). However, my initial issue still exist with dSYM is not being automatically uploaded.