# My DSYMs stopped to be uploaded to Crashlytics

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics

I setup teamcity for daily builds and everything seemed to work some time ago (I was able to see crash reports in crashlytics dashboard). But now build machine is not sending dsyms at all. I added Crashlytics from CocoaPods:

```
pod 'CrashlyticsFramework', '~> 2.2'
```

I have tripple checked api key and secret. Here's my run script:

```
./Pods/CrashlyticsFramework/Crashlytics.framework/run <myKey> <mySecret>
```

In teamcity build logs, I can see script was executed:

```
2015-02-02 18:01:43.511 run[7213:507] Crashlytics.framework/run 1.3.11
```

But I don't see any log entry about DSYM being uploaded to Crashlytics like [Hudson shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774547/is-there-a-manual-for-the-run-command-in-crashlytics-framework). So, if I make a build directly to device from Xcode then it shows the crash (and probably sends DSYM). But if it's made through build machine then dsym is not send. I know that because I see missing dsym with the build version when I go to crashlytics dashboard. Any ideas how to debug or see log why DSYMs are not sent?

Comment: Crashlytics is now part of the [Fabric.io](http://Fabric.io.), I therefor use `pod 'Fabric'` and `pod 'Fabric/Crashlytics'`, may the old API is no longer supported?

Comment: @rckoenes I'v removed Crashlytics from pods, then added both of these lines to podfile but now I'm getting duplicate symbols. It looks like Fabric and Crashlytics had the same classes or methods defined. Then I removed  pod 'Fabric' and left pod 'Fabric/Crashlytics'. But now I'm getting symbols not found :) Fabric mac app is also helping with that as it doesn't understand workspace. Any ideas?

Comment: No ideas, I've been trying some things, on my system everything is working. I'm using the latest Fabrico.IO app and both `pod 'Fabric'` and `pod 'Fabric/Crashlytics'`.

Comment: @rckoenes After cleaning, upgrading and etc. and I managed to get it running. But after couple commits I soon started getting duplicate symbols as described here: https://github.com/zergtmn/Fabric/issues/5#issuecomment-86094359 . I posted a comment and will try suggestion explicitly define fabric and crashlytics pod versions.

Comment: I just started running into this now (Crashlytics failing to upload dSYMs), and found a workaround. Posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35374481/2397068