# issue with uploading dSYM to crashlytics

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, crashlytics, fabric.io

To upload dSYM to crashlytics, I have following setup but not able to get dSYM uploaded.

In my target -> build phases -> Run Script

```
./Fabric.framework/run KEY SECRET

 echo "working"

./Crashlytics.framework/run KEY SECRET
```

In Report navigator

```
2015-03-27 11:45:32.868 run[12108:507] Fabric.framework/run 1.3.13
working
2015-03-27 11:45:36.000 run[12109:507] Crashlytics.framework/run 1.3.13
```

In my app fabric.io dashboard

Missing dSYM

What i'm missing?

Comment: Did you find a solution around this?

Answer (score 17):

If you have bitcode on because you want app-thinning or a TVOS or WatchOS app, then the dSYMs you create when you generate the xcarchive are NOT the dSYMs required. This is because apple *re-compiles* from the bitcode. To get the real dSYMs, go to itunesconnect, open up the specific (processed) build, and hit the "Download dSYMs" link.  Apparently fastlane can automate this process (I have not tried it): https://krausefx.com/blog/download-dsym-symbolication-files-from-itunes-connect-for-bitcode-ios-apps

Comment: I was trying to use the dysm files given to me from buddybuild, which did not work. The ones direct from itunesconnect did, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: It may be worth noting that apparently bitcode is on by default with new apps.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK, You install the fabric software on your mac, on which you are making your build or archive, as soon as you make an archive, it automatically asks for your permission and uploads the dsym file.

Also see [Fabric Integration Troubleshooting](https://dev.twitter.com/crashlytics/ios), see 4 point under **TroubleShooting**

It’s possible, but rare, that we are missing a dSYM to symbolicate any crash reports. There will be an alert on your dashboard if this is the case. Click through to upload the missing dSYM. Keep in mind that exceptions are not guaranteed to crash. The full code path, including code in system libraries, matters here. If you aren’t seeing the dSYM alert, you can go to your app’s settings page, and append “/mappings” to the URL to reach it, e.g. https://fabric.io/settings/apps//mappings

Comment: I see the alert on the dashboard and successfully upload the dsym file in the next page. Had to zip the dsym file. After doing that the message keeps coming up.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a tool to upload the dSym files:

https://github.com/prsolucoes/fabric-upload-dsym

This tool is open source and made with golang. It can simplify the upload process without any other tool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have everything in place--double, triple checked--and I'm having the same problem now. The dSYM always fails to automatically upload. I think Apple changed something about how apps with bitcode are processed so that UUIDs are changing and causing problems with dSYM files. There's more information [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/not-matching-uuid-bitcode/61000), and I posted a workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35374388/2397068.