# Crashlytics: "We're missing a dSYM to process crashes"

Tags: ios, xcode7, crashlytics, dsym

Crashlytics says "We're missing a dSYM to process crashes" and when I try to download dSYMs from Xcode (7.1), I get "there are no dsyms available for download"

Comment: I also have the the same issue, it appears a few people may: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159244/xcode-there-are-no-dsyms-available-for-download

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 93):

I ran into the same problem today. It seems that iTunes Connect is recompiling apps with bitcode so that the UUID changes, and the dSYM inside the .xcarchive can't actually be used to symbolicate the app (this appears to be a new development).

You can download the correct dSYM from iTunes Connect. Login, go to My Apps, select your app, then tap on the Activity tab at the top. Tap on the relevant build, and, assuming the app was submitted with symbols in the first place, you should see the option to "Download dSYM."

The file you get is called dSYMs (without an extension) but it is in fact a zip file. Add the .zip extension, unzip, and you'll find your dSYM(s) inside.

You can upload this .zip file directly to Crashlytics and you should be all set.

The solution was posted here: https://twittercommunity.com/t/not-matching-uuid-bitcode/61000

Comment: The dSYMs downloaded from iTunes Connect still did not contain any of those reported missing from the Fabric Dashboard. (At least in my case.)

Comment: Hi @KyleH, that's odd, are you certain you've got the right app with the right bundle ID and right version number? If you're still stuck you should ask for help here, I found them pretty responsive: https://twittercommunity.com/c/fabric

Comment: Hey @LaneRettig! I ended up disabling bitcode for my project, archiving a new build, and then the dSYMs were automatically uploaded. So I guess I'll just have to leave bitcode disabled until their is another workaround.

Comment: I had the same problem as Kyle H. Oddly enough, after uploading a new build it has been fixed. I still have some past issues though that I can't see due to not being able to find the correct dSYMs

Comment: When downloading the dSYMs from iTunes Connect, I never have to add the .zip extension. It downloads as a zip folder in the first place.

Comment: Hi @user3344977, thanks for the comment. I checked again just now and I'm definitely still getting a file called "dSYMs" without an extension from iTunes Connect! I wonder if it doesn't have something to do with browser or platform (I'm using Chrome on OS X).

Comment: @LaneRettig it probably does have something to do with that :)

Comment: @LaneRettig What do you mean by "assuming the app was submitted with symbols in the first place"? Do you mean, the 'Include symbols' checkbox was ticked during app upload to iTunes Connect? Or do you mean, the archive contained dSYMs inside? Or something else? I see no option in iTunes Connect to download symbols for my app.

Comment: Yes, I meant that "include symbols" was checked when the app was submitted.

Comment: I don't have an app created in iTunes Connect. I'm only archiving the app to send over the air installations. SO can't I still use the dSYM files inside the .xcarchive?

Comment: Make sure you're using **Safari**. When using Chrome to download missing dSYMs from iTunes Connect & upload them to Fabric, I would always get an upload error. Switching to Safari did the trick.

Comment: @DerekSoike it's been almost two days i'm trying to upload using Chrome, switching safari is the key. You're a life saver.

Comment: do i need to do this every once in a while, or do i do it only once ?

Comment: What about "Optional" dsyms? Where can I get them?

Answer (score 28):

There is another way to get to your dSYM.

1. From the organizer, right click on the archive and select "Show in Finder"
2. Right click on the .xcarchive shown in Finder and select "Show Package Contents"
3. Copy the "dSYMs" folder found inside to somewhere else.
4. Compress the "dSYMs" folder and upload it to Crashlytics.

Comment: This didn't work for me. The UUID in the dSYM file inside the xcarchive does not match the one in Crashlytics. See my answer for more.

Comment: still firebase console shows missing dSYMs

Answer (score 17):

If anyone cannot find the dSYM file in the .archive package or on iTunes Connect like me, please check `Build Settings -> Debug Information Format -> Release -> DWARF with dSYM File` is correctly set.

Comment: that s worked thanks

Answer (score 8):

@Shawn's answer actually helped me fix this permanently for my instance, with **no need to upload dSYMs manually**. Basically go to `Build Settings` and then turn on these parameters:

- **Debug:** DWARF with dSYM File
- **Release:** DWARF with dSYM File
- **Enable Bitcode:** No

This seems to work well when you've NOT gone through the iTunes Connect path yet and just want to test your app with Crashlytics in the "development" mode.

Comment: This helped me, but **Bitecode** is enabled in my case.

Comment: This helped me and **Bitecode** is enabled in my case too. Thank You!!

Answer (score 6):

Check in your Build Settings that your Debug Information Format is “DWARF with dSYM File” for both Debug and Release.

[Features](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/features)