# Missing dSYM files in Fabric Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

Since yesterday I try to configure Twitter Crashlytics in my iOS app. 
I have a problem w dSYMs files. Fabric dashboard show me message "We are missing dSYMs files" so I uploaded the files by online manager (redirect from this message) and this message was shown: 
[image]

but if I go back to dashboard the message that system missing dSYMS files is shown again.. and again. 
What I have to do?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I'd run this command:

dwarfdump -u <PathToAppsDsym>

that you're uploading and make sure that the UUID matches the one that is reported as missing.

Comment: @MikeBonnell In the dSYMs folder there are lot of files (including pods dSYMs). Do I need to submit all these files? Or else just the  myapp.app.dSYM file?

Comment: Any of the ones reported as missing should be uploaded. If you have many dSYMs, I'd recommend using the upload-symbols script with the following syntax:

/Applications/Fabric.app/Contents/MacOS/upload-symbols -a APIKey -p ios /Users/mbonnell/Documents/PathToDsym

Comment: @MikeBonnell What if the dSYM doesn't exist because crashes were generated in debug before DWARF was enabled in debug? How do we get rid of the warning then?

Comment: The warning is removed in a week without the corresponding dSYMs being uploaded.

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the same issue. I tried following all of the steps that Crashlytics recommends, including the one that @Mike helpfully posted, to no avail.

I finally found a workaround and posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35374388/2397068. You need to download the dSYM from iTunes Connect.

Comment: If a question is a duplicate, please flag it as such, linking to your other answer - in general please avoid posting link-only answers like this one. Thank you. :)

Comment: Thanks @EricD. I don't think I have a high enough reputation to mark as a duplicate. Apologies if I've misunderstood something!

Comment: You may not "close as duplicate" yet, but you can already "flag as duplicate". :) No worries, Stack Overflow is a complex platform, it takes time to get the subtleties of its rules and guidelines.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for letting me know. Will try that next time.

Comment: Does this mean, I need to upload the dSYM every time I upload a new build. How to fix this permanently?

Comment: Hey @Hokage take a look at the commentary on the other thread, http://stackoverflow.com/a/35374388/2397068. Your question may have been answered there!