# Crashlytics (without Fabric) not showing crash iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I have problem with Crashlytics not showing crashes on Firebase dashboard only the testing phone that is connect to my Mac is showing. I followed the instruction on Firebase doc. and did the force crash testing on the testing phone it did show the crash on Firebase. However, when I upload the new build the user's crash did not show in the dashboard. Can anyone help me with that? (I just install Crashlytics last week so I didn't use Fabric) Thanks!!!!

This is the pod I have:

```
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Core' 
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
```

What I have in AppDelegate

```
import Firebase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseCrashlytics

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
}
```

Build setting's Debug Information Format: DWARF with dSYM File
Uploaded Crashlytics symbols "Successfully uploaded Crashlytics symbols" response

My Crashlytics dSYMs still show it is missing. I uploaded the Crashlytics symbols yesterday.

**Updated: I found the problem and the solutions. Please check the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

** Updated on 11/08/2021

The problem that is making the crush not show on the dashboard was because of the missing dSYMs. Here is the solutions steps:

1. Go to Firebase Crashlytics > dSYMs > Missing dSYMs. Check the UUID and the version number (which build).
2. Go to AppStoreConnect > My App > TestFlight > find the correspond build number & version number > Build Metadata > includes Symbols > Download dSYM (make sure when you upload a new build check enable bitcode
3. Open the downloaded file "appDsyms" and find the matching missing UUID and run

   path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols
   -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs

in the terminal. You should see the missing ddSYMs shows "Uploaded".

Once it is uploaded you should see the full crush reports on the dashboard.

Here is the reference I found on SOF

1. [Missing dSYM files in Fabric Crashlytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35059733/missing-dsym-files-in-fabric-crashlytics)
2. [Crashlytics: “We're missing a dSYM to process crashes”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077722/crashlytics-were-missing-a-dsym-to-process-crashes/35374388#35374388)