# Xcode - There are no dSYMs available for download

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, dsym

I want to extract the dSYM file from but when I click on *"Download dSYMs..."* in the *Organizer* I get the follow message: "There are no dSYMs available for download.".

I'm using Xcode 7.2 with a workspace generated by Cocoapods 0.39.

How can I get them?

[image]

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am getting the same issue and the dSYM inside the package is missing the ones I am looking for.

Comment: No, it's been a pain. I can't see any crashes for my app. This was probably introduced by Xcode 7.2.

Comment: Same issue here... if you make any progress please do post it here!

Comment: @Jordan Of course. Any ideas on your end?

Comment: @FelipePeña well I noticed when inspecting the .xcarchive that there *already* seemed to be a DSYM folder inside. It didn't work to desymbolicate the crash logs though... I'm wondering if somehow the app was built with dsym files, then when iTunes Connect recompiles with bit code and produces new dsysms or however it works, we can't download because for some reason we already had dsym files... ?

Comment: We are planning to submit another build today. I'll let you know if we have the same issue with the new build. Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68)

Comment: @jhk ok. I don't think it's the real answer but I'm using Fabric and Crashlytics and those libraries seem to mess a bit the Cocoapods library package that gets attached to the workspace. If you agree this is something important, I can post details.

Comment: I am doing the same. I want to point out that it worked perfectly fine with the build before that.

Comment: @FelipePeña so we got a new build up and it was able to download the other dSYMs without any problems. I am beginning to suspect it had to do something with submitting with version 7.1 and upgrading Xcode in between...

Comment: @jhk thanks for the update. I think that too. Upgrading to Xcode 7.2...

Comment: @FelipePeña spoke to soon. :( I am seeing few "hashed" dSYMs in the folder but I don't see the few missing on Crashlytics. Do you know of a way to reset Xcode to redownload the dSYMs? It looks like it's being cached somewhere. I tried deleting the whole folder but it's still saying "All of the available dSYMs have already been downloaded.".

Comment: Bitcode must be enabled to download from iTunesConnect. My answer has been added to the list below.

Comment: In my case, for fabric test, I added some bug into my codes after the first launch in the fabric. so in this scenario, the fabric couldn't find symbols and also I couldn't find related dsyms. I recreated a new app and all things are OK

Answer (score 341):

> NON-BITCODE

Here's a GIF on how to get DSYMS, compress and upload to crashlytics/fabric

[image]

1. Press Window > Organizer
2. Right-click on your app> Show in Finder
3. Right-click on first .xcarchive file > Show package contents

---

> BITCODE ENABLED

You'll need to download dsyms from App Store Connect. The easiest would be to use [fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/download_dsyms/#download_dsyms)

```
lane :refresh_dsyms do
    download_dsyms                  # Download dSYM files from App Store Connect
    
    upload_symbols_to_crashlytics   # Optional for uploading to Crashlytics
end
```

Comment: But why Xcode download option is not working? do you have any idea?

Comment: This didn't work for me directly from the package contents. I had to copy the dSYMs folder to another folder first and then compress it.  See details in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47193122/1203475.

Comment: I needed to run this command in the /dSYM/ folder to compress: `zip -r SymbolFiles.zip *.dSYM`

Comment: The question is from "Download DSYMs" button. why it is not downloading by clicking the button? why we have to get it manually?

Comment: I added the steps below the GIF. I hope it helps!

Comment: I tried your solution and uploaded it to crashlytics, it says upload successfull but when I reload the page I still get same error, any ideas?

Comment: It is a different issue, but looks like you uploaded the wrong binary which doesn't match to what crashlytics is looking for

Comment: This is not true for bitcode-enable apps! Bitcode-enabled apps will have different dsym files created by the appstore for the appstore versions.

Comment: Even more applicable now with Xcode 14. Thank you for the demonstration GIF too. Nice touch.

Answer (score 48):

I think @Jordan is correct--it seems that iTunes Connect is recompiling apps with bitcode so that the UUID changes, and the dSYM inside the .xcarchive can't actually be used to symbolicate the app (this appears to be a new development).

You can download the correct dSYM from iTunes Connect. Login, go to My Apps, select your app, then tap on the Activity tab at the top. Tap on the relevant build, and, assuming the app was submitted with symbols in the first place, you should see the option to "Download dSYM."

The file you get is called dSYMs (without an extension) but it is in fact a zip file. Add the .zip extension, unzip, and you'll find your dSYM(s) inside.

(I needed to do this this week since Crashlytics was complaining about a missing dSYM.)

Comment: So I need to submit my app to iTunesConnect first to get the dSYM file and to upload it to fabric.io?

Comment: My app, which is in the app store currently, says "Includes Symbols: Yes" in iTunesConnect yet there is NO ability to download .dSYM

Comment: @swalkner I can't remember exactly. I want to say that I found my situation was not possible to fix :/

Answer (score 24):

Actually you can't download dSYM file from iTunesConnect now. There is another way to get that file.

Xcode -> Window -> Organizer -> Show xcarchive file in Finder -> Right Click Your xcarchive file -> Select "Show Package Contents"

You can see your dSYM file now.

Comment: Seems like you can today... When you select a desired build, there is "download dsym" button.

Answer (score 22):

## bitcode must be enabled

if you want to get your `dSYM` from iTunesConnect

- Build Settings > Build Options > `Enable Bitcode` > **YES**
- Select device "*Generic iOS Device*" (or anything that works)
- `Archive`

**When exporting from archive**

- **CHECK** "*include app symbols for your application to receive symbolicated crash logs from Apple*"
- **CHECK** "*include bitcode*"

**Upload using Application Loader**

Once your app has been *successfully* uploaded to iTunesConnect you can go to iTunesConnect.com > MyApps > [YOUR APP] > Activity > All Builds > [YOUR BUILD] > General Information > Includes Symbols > **Download dSYM**

#xcode8.2.1 #osx10.12.6

Comment: True story. If you don't have bitcode enabled, Apple will merely show, "includes symbols: Yes" without the Download link.

Comment: True, Dan Rosenstark. For me, AFTER uploading to iTunesConnect, I had to use Xcode's Organiser and click the "Download dSYM" which didn't give an error, but apparently did nothing (no files appeared anywhere??), but then in iTunesConnect, the blue link appeared next to "Includes Symbols Yes". It's a maze.

Comment: Somehow the link doesn't appear in App Store Connect, even with dSYM and bitcode enabled. Only Includes Symbols: Yes

Answer (score 11):

I've found a solution from https://twittercommunity.com/t/not-matching-uuid-bitcode/61000/2

"Crashlytics was reporting missing dSYMs with UUID looking like this: 83889b11dedd363c8e5ee56233bcc90c. 
As I said, I followed the guide7 but I couldn't find that UUID. So I went in the iTunesConnect and I did the following:

- Select the app
- Choose the Activity tab on top
- Select the build version Crashlytics is complaining about
- Click the Download dSYM blue link

The downloaded file is called dSYM has no extension but it is actually a zip. So I added the zip extension and unzipped it. Inside the unzipped folder I found many dSYM files, one on which has called 83889B11-DEDD-363C-8E5E-E56233BCC90C.dSYM which matched the UUID Crashlytics was reporting as missing (even if formatted in a different way). Note also that this file is not inside the xcarchive.

Hope it can help!"

in my case, it works like charms

Comment: I don't see that blue link inside of iTunes Connect. I remember I saw this reply in another thread. Do you know what specific section is at?

Comment: @FelipePeña iTunesConnect -> My Apps -> "Your App" -> Activity -> All Builds -> Select Build -> Build Details

Comment: @spacemonkey Can't find anything there

Comment: Same for me, there is no link to download the dSYMs

Comment: I think download dSYMs has been removed. I no longer see it in itunes connect :(

Comment: Wasted half of my day trying to find the source of the problem. In the end it was Apple started using .dsm extension for dSYM files. Renamed it to .zip as @Davide suggested. Tnx mate!

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I could not find a dSYM file of my app in the Archives folder. If you face this, go to your **Project Build Settings** > **Build Options** > **Debug Information Format** and make sure it is set to **DWARF with dSYM file**

Comment: This is set, still "No dSYMs were found for Version x.x Build xx"

Comment: I have had the same issue, switching the above mentioned setting solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**If dSYMs folder in package contents is empty** (Ted's answer), try to check:

- Build Settings > Build Options > **Enable Bitcode** is set to **YES** (Jacksonkr's answer)
- Build Settings > Build Options > **Debug Information Format** is set to **DWARF with dSYM file** (daisura99's answer)

**Please check them both.**

Then in show package contents -> dSYMs folder, this time, you should find something.

In my case, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Form latest updates you no need to upload dSYM files manually, automatic upload is done with below process.

**Step-1:** Goto Target-> Build Settings -> Search for "debug information format". Set Debug Information Format to **DWARF with dSYM File** for all your build types.

[image]

**Step-2:** Goto Build Phases -> Expand **Run Script** and add **script & input files**

In Script:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
```

In input files:

```
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}
    $(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)
```

Example Screenshot:

[image]

**Step-3:** Finally add one more script to upload dSYM files

```
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp 
      ${PROJECT_DIR}/Your_path/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios 
      ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}
```

[image]

Here, in the 2nd line of the script **${PROJECT_DIR}/Your_path/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios** update with your project path means your app **schema name**

If you got error while running the app follow my answer [Xcode 10.2.1 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code/69883902#69883902)

Error:

```
 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: Step 3 runs the script when we install the pod but when we use the package that time which script needs to write for upload dSYM from XCode

Comment: @ S K, I don't have idea, check with other answers.