# Using Crashlytics with iOS 9.2 Missing dSYMs

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I just installed Crashlytics in my app yesterday and I'm having trouble trying to track down the missing dSYMs that it warns me about in their Dashboard. Currently running Xcode v7.2.1 and building for iOS 9.2

I'm pretty sure I've followed each current Stackoverflow answer to this problem to no avail. I've tried:

1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35256515/3403364)
2. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35374370/3403364)
3. And I have already tried to go into the Xcode Organizer and downloading the dSYMs from there but it says there are none to download.

Is there another way to find these or am I just unable to use Crashlytics in my app?

Answer (score 1):

After looking around some more I have found a solution (or just a workaround). By disabling bitcode in my project Build Settings, Fabric is able to automatically collect my dSYMs on build. Also, I have additional frameworks included as `.xcodeproj` files in my app, so these must also have bitcode disabled.