# Cannot compress dSyms

Tags: xcode, macos, zip, compression, dsym

I need to compress dSYMs folder that contains dSYM file
But i'm stuck
[image]

Good thing is, I was able to compress using commandline

```
zip -r outputFile.zip *.dSYM
```

Comment: Try to copy dSYMs to the Desktop and compress it from there. If this fails also, try a 3rd party zip tool like keka or command line tools.

Comment: i did that and commandline works. How do i teach finder to use recursive zip

Comment: The "Archive Utility" application has very limited preferences. You can open the application `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Archive Utility.app` and open the Preferences (Archive Utility Menu -> Preferences) to find out what's possible.

Comment: This is very weird, we've also hit this problem at our company. Has anyone managed to figure out why this is happening exactly? Copying the dSYMs folder somewhere else and then compressing it through Finder works fine, but refuses to work in-place...

Comment: where are you uploading the dSYMs? You can try fastlane so you don't need to compress and upload

Comment: This is apparently a known bug. My report was closed as duplicate. [rdar://35048759](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5491571675889664)

Answer (score 3):

Command line works for me everytime

```
zip -r dysm.zip {GUID}.dSYM
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I was able to work around it by copying the dSYMs folder from my package contents to my hard drive.  Then I could zip it instantly.  I think the issue is trying to compress from the package contents.

I followed the steps from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39361649/1203475)  but instead of compressing from the package contents I copied it to another folder then compressed.