# Firebase Crashlytics: Upload missing dSYMs to see crashes from 1 versions.(iOS)

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, deobfuscation

**Error Message:** *Upload missing dSYMs to see crashes from 1 versions.
Versions affected: 1.0 (1)*

I am trying to implement Firebase Crashlytics in my iOS project. I did all the setups according to [Firebase Crashlytics Doucmentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/?authuser=0). The crash is performed manually when the button is clicked just to see whether the crashlytics is working.

```
@IBAction func onTestCrashButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {

    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()

}
```

But when i tried to see the error report in the firebase console, it shows something like this image.

[image]

After reading [Get Deobfuscated crash reports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?authuser=0) I just Set Debug Information Format to ***DWARF with dSYM File*** like below but the problem not fixed till now.
[image]

Comment: It would be really good if there was just an option to clear this warning until any further dSyms go missing.

Comment: If you're still having those issues, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159244/xcode-there-are-no-dsyms-available-for-download#answer-39361649

Comment: For latest update everyone should follow @Dipak answer, it's working...

Comment: Another thing to check is that "For install builds only" is not checked in the Build Phases tab. That fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I have been having this same issue for a while and I was finally able to resolve it, thought I would share what worked for me:

For context, I am working on a larger app which uses several Cocoapods.

I found that same red banner on my Firebase Crashlytics page and after following all of their [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports) I was still seeing it.

I tried the "archive/find .dSYMs/upload manually via terminal" solution several times to no avail.

Finally, I decided to download the .dSYMs from iTunesConnect.
[Your App] > Activity > [Desired Build Number] > Download dSYM

I then uploaded those .dSYMs manually and within minutes Firebase Crashlytics was happy and showing the crash reports.

**UPDATE**
Google has added a swanky .dSYM upload feature on the Firebase Crashlytics dashboard, no more uploading from the terminal.

**Edit on March 16, 2020.**

Google is soon removing the upload feature on the Firebase Dashboard. An uploader script should be used from the terminal to upload dSYMs to Firebase. See Google's instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports#run-upload-symbols-script-manually).

Comment: Also the file you downloaded for iTunes, was it live? was crashlytics integrated to it or not?

Comment: Yes to all three. The .dSYM file can be located locally for any build, but iTunesConnect will only have it for builds that you’ve uploaded to iTunesConnect (which could include test builds). It is live and yes Crashlytics is integrated via Firebase.

Comment: download the .dSYMs from iTunesConnect really helped. Thanks

Comment: I did download from iTunes and upload to firebase, but it still getting the error.

Comment: @JoeyNelson I use App Store Connect to download my dSYMs. When I upload those onto Firebase, the get successfully uploaded. But, I won't see the reports even after a few hours or a day. I need to get in touch with Firebase support and share them my dSYMs and only when they do it from their end, it works for me. My app is Bitcode enabled, which I guess most apps are these days.

Comment: Why did Google decide to remove the upload feature in their Firebase UI... -_- it was very convenient!!

Comment: How can we use uploader script for this? Can anyone give the example of this.

Comment: What is an uploader script? How to use it?

Comment: Added a link to Google's instructions on how to manually upload using a script.

Comment: why firebase removed uploading dysm file on console itself?? runing script doesnt help me

Comment: @ParthGrover, DrorBar, 
Here's uploader script documentation: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios#upload-dsyms

Comment: Worth noting that you **must** download the dSYMs from App Store Connect (formerly iTunes Connect) if you have bitcode enabled, because your local dSYMs will be different from the ones that map to your app in the store.

Comment: Is there any method to auto-upload this file with the new version release? Or do need to upload the file after every version release using the terminal command?

Answer (score 218):

1. Download appDsyms archive from App Store

   1.1 Login: https://appstoreconnect.apple.com

   1.2 Go to: MyApps -> Choose your app -> Test Flight -> Select app version that is in the App Store -> Build Metadata -> Includes Symbols (right side) -> Press: **Download dSYM**.

**New way - June 2022**

New way to upload directly in Firebase Crashlytics.
Go to firebase crashlytics https://console.firebase.google.com
-> Select your project -> Go to crashlytics (left side) -> Upload your dSYM files.

[image]

**Other way - Upload dSYM files via terminal**

1. Open terminal, drag and drop 3 files on terminal on this order:

   1.1 drag an drop: "upload-symbols" which can be found in
   `/project/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols`

   1.2 write " `-gsp` "

   1.3 drag an drop: "GoogleService-Info.plist" which can be found in `/project/GoogleService-Info.plist`

   1.4 write " `-p ios` "

   1.5 drag an drop: "appDsyms" folder (unarchived, zip file might not work!) which usually is in Download folder `/Users/username/Downloads/appDsyms`

   1.6 Press `Enter`

In terminal the complete command should include `-gsp` and `-p ios`, full command looks like this: `1.1 -gsp 1.3 -p ios 1.5`

```
/project/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /project/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /Users/username/Downloads/appDsyms
```

**All Set, wait for upload in the terminal!**

Terminal example:
[image]

-

One way how to get a file or folder location with a drag and drop to terminal:

[image]

-

AppStore Connect, Download dSYM:

[image]

Comment: I did this and got `Successfully uploaded Crashlytics symbols` message in the console. Bu the red error is still in my firebase console

Comment: I am not using pods, anyone can help me.

Comment: Is there a way to have Firebase do this automatically? Or every time I have to manually download the dsym from Apple?

Comment: Thanks man this is the best way that i found to upload this files. I think before was great but this new version is horrible

Comment: /Pods/Fabric: is a directory

Comment: There is no Activity in App Store Connect. I downloaded dSYMs this way: My App -> Build -> Build Metadata -> Include Symbols (Yes) | Download dSYMs.

Comment: Worked for me by do using the zip file

Comment: @Hibbem good to hear that. I will update the answer. Thank you!

Comment: In latest update Download dSYMs not available..

Comment: Everyone should follow @Dipak answer, it's working...

Comment: @Naresh not needed!

Comment: If we are not using appstore, how do we get the dSYMs? Do we need the original xcarchive?

Comment: @CyberMew can you please try this method by Michael Long:
ust to bring this up to date as of Xcode 12.2, Apple is allowing Xcode to download the symbols.
1) Go to the Organizer and find the app you uploaded to the store.
2) Click the Download Debug Symbols button beneath Details.
3) Right-click the app and Show In Finder.
4) Right-click the xcarchive and Show Package Contents
5) Your dSYMs are in the folder...

Comment: got "Successfully uploaded Crashlytics symbols" message in the console. But the red error is still in my firebase console. any one know that when firebase error will gone ?

Comment: It can be that Firebase takes up to 24h to process the files. Normally I experienced 10-20 minutes. This workflow is outdated, since Xcode 14 the symbols are not longer downloadable from AppStore Connect. Please refer to @Dipak's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64782202/12035498

Comment: @EgzonP. I have added dSYMs using terminal and drag and drop the zip file then i am able to see crashes in firebase > dashboard but still i am getting that warning(Upload missing dSYMs to see crashes from 1 versions.) in red colour why?  here is my post could you please guide me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76370863/firebase-crashlytics-upload-1-dsym-file-to-process-them-error-why

Comment: That was detailed explanation thank you

Answer (score 88):

After updating **Fabric Crashlytics** to **Firebase Crashlytics** SDK. I was also getting same issue(**Upload 1 missing dSYM required to process 5 crashes**). I solved with the help of following steps-:

**Step 1-:**
Open Target-> Build Settings -> Search for "debug information format".
Set **Debug Information Format** to **DWARF with dSYM File** for all
your build types.

[image]
**Step 2-:**
Open Run Script section and input the script

"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"

*and then add input files-*

```
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}
$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)
```

[image]

**Step 3-:** Add one more script to upload dSYM file

```
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/Your_path/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}
```

[image]

Comment: My main issue is I no longer receive critical emails from Crashlytics due to missing dSYMs. Crashlytics only recognises crashes after I manually upload dSYMs. Which means I'm not getting any notifications unless I remember each day/week to upload dSYMs. Does your solution enable this work? Meaning no more red banner and I get crash reports as-they-happen after implementing your solution?

Comment: @ErimFranci This solution will probably solve your red banner problem. After the proper set up you need to enable Crashlytics email alert notification if it is not enable.

Comment: if not using pods of firebase then which need to use a run script?
I am using the framework of firebase crash analytics.
@Deepak please help me with the issue of getting DSYM missing.

Comment: @nipa I did not try without pod, but i think in place of ${PODS_ROOT} use FirebaseCrashlytics directory path in step 2. Remaining steps will be same.

Comment: What is the point using run (which should upload the dsym in background) and later upload-symbols? Thanks!

Comment: Anyone know which Crashlytics path we should use for step 3 if we're using Swift Package Manager instead of CocoaPods?

Comment: @DEVIGNR `${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/Your_path/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}`

Comment: This is the latest solution, working fine....

Comment: Successfully uploaded Crashlytics symbols. But still Its showing this message: "Upload missing required dSYMs". How much time will it take to reflect in the dashboard or Do i need to crash the app again?

Comment: Do we need to upload the same UDID dSYMs files? Actually i don't have same UDID.

Comment: @Tharani not required dSYMs file, here defining the path where dSYMs files stores. Instead of my path (Your_path) you need to mention your path.

Comment: @Dipak Thanks for the reply. I have tried the same. But still i could not see the crashlogs.

Comment: The 3rd step freezes when used in an Xcode Build Phase. You just need to call `${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -bp -gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/ProjectName/GoogleService-Info.plist`. Note the `-bp` flag, which can be replaced by `--build-phase`. It as been made on purpose.

Comment: @Dipak This one is no longer working. Is there any other solution ?

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya This is really the less documented problem...

Comment: @ΩlostA Yes, you are right. Google disappointed very much in Firebase Crashlytics. Except for integration flow, nothing is properly documented that uploads dsyms automatically .

Comment: @Dipak I have added dSYMs using terminal and drag and drop the zip file then i am able to see crashes in firebase > dashboard but still i am getting that warning(Upload missing dSYMs to see crashes from 1 versions.) in red colour why?  here is my post could you please guide me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76370863/firebase-crashlytics-upload-1-dsym-file-to-process-them-error-why

Comment: This is a good answer, but it was not working for me until I notices an error that even in firebase documentation is present, this line: $(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH) is written wrong, it should use curly braces instead of parentheses, like this: ${SRCROOT}/${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}.

Answer (score 27):

If everything is fine you setup all without missing any step and then also you see **Upload missing dSYMs to see crashes** error in firebase. 

#### (New way - June 2022)

**You can upload directly in Firebase Crashlytics.** Go to firebase crashlytics https://console.firebase.google.com -> Select your project -> Go to crashlytics (left side) -> Upload your dSYM files.

[image]

> Download the **.dSYMs** from **iTunesConnect** only no anywhere else and upload those to the **Firebase**.

[image]

**Another way - Upload dSYM files via terminal**

> Run the script directly from your terminal to upload **dSYMs** :

```
/path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs
```

After two days of long research and try lots of solutions but no anyone works for me :(

But by this solution **Firebase Crashlytics was happy and showing the crash reports within a few minutes.**

Comment: Even after uploading the issue is still same.....script didn't throw any error

Comment: @Satyam Can you Uploaded dSYMs  through terminal ?

Comment: I am able to upload the dSYM files as mentioned in the command. But still I don't see any updates in the Crashlytics web page.

Comment: @Satyam What's you see on Crashlytics Dashboard? I mean are you see there your app version or anything else ?

Comment: I think it will take some time to reflect the dSYM files in the google console. Its working good now.

Comment: @Satyam Yes it will take few minutes to reflect. Please Upvote the answer so others can see the relevance :)

Comment: I'm getting this error please help me " No such file or directory /path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols "

Comment: @SaikumarReddy Here **/path/to/** is equal to you your project directory path

Comment: @SaikumarReddy If you Solve the issue Please Upvote the answer so others can see the relevance :)

Comment: I am not using pods, @NikunjKumbhani could you help me

Comment: @guru Then you can replace the path with your **upload-symbols** project directory path and then upload via that path from terminal

Comment: i do not have upload-symbols, from where i can find it, i just download firebase,zip from https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#integrate-without-cocoapods

Comment: /Pods/Fabric: is a directory

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani I have added dSYMs using terminal and drag and drop the zip file then i am able to see crashes in firebase > dashboard but still i am getting that warning(Upload missing dSYMs to see crashes from 1 versions.) in red colour why?  here is my post could you please guide me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76370863/firebase-crashlytics-upload-1-dsym-file-to-process-them-error-why

Comment: Did they remove the option to download the dsym file from the TestFlight tab or do you need special permissions for it?

Answer (score 8):

```
Pods/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp APP/Resources/GoogleService_Info.plist -p ios /Users/ME/Desktop/APP.app.dSYM
```

This one I used recently to upload my dsym to fabric. I was using fabric with crashlytics SDK not firebase one(which is currently in beta). Just replace your app name for 'APP' and your DSYM path instead of '/Users/ME/Desktop/APP.app.dSYM.

Comment: Would you please add an explanation

Comment: Firebase no more allows adding DSYMs file by just uploading, above mentioned command works for me to upload DSYMs files by opening terminal at project's root folder and giving path to google service plist and your dsyms directory.

Answer (score 8):

- use package `firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.1`.
- in Run script add this line only `${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run`
- in input files add this line only `$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)`
- run the project and error should gone.

Note. This solution works only on flutter.
[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm. Except I already had some lines inside my "run script", so I just added the line you suggested to the end.

Answer (score 7):

I also faced the same issue.
Basically I was missing a simple step that is why Firebase script could not upload dSYM file.

**Step followed to solve it.**

- Click on project file
- Select target
- Go to build settings
- Search "debug information format"
- For all scheme change the settings to "DWARF with dYSM file"

[image: xCode setting screen]

- Now run the project again
- dYSM error of firebase dashboard should go...

Comment: This fixed the issue with dSYM for me. It automatically uploaded to Firebase.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I have done the following things and it worked:

1. Select 'Run script only when installing' in Build Phases -> Run Script 
   (Shell = ${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run)
2. Build the app
3. Now you can find the .dsym file in the path, 
   /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-arctjcalvfslmbakanpyivuuxjmm/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos
4. Upload the zipped .dsym file to firebase console
5. After few minutes, you can find the crash reports

NOTE:

- I have disabled bitcode while exporting ipa file (Adhoc or Appstore)
- If you need ipa with bitcode enabled, then download dsym file from iTunes connect

Comment: I don't get any file inside the /Library/Developer/Xcode file path

Comment: How to upload dsym to crashlytics?

Answer (score 6):

Find and upload debug symbols for Crashlytics

- Copy the UUID of your missing dSYM and run
  `mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == <UUID>"` on a terminal window.
- The above command will return something like `.../build/ios/Release-Staging-iphoneos/your.app.dSYM`
- Zip up the package and upload to Crashlytics using Firebase dashboard

Wait for 10-15 minutes before the crashes start to appear on the console.

Comment: this returned 0 results for me.. what to do?

Comment: Try running it from your home directory if that makes a difference and check for spaces and special characters when copying from the web.

Answer (score 5):

**March 2021**

The activity tab is no longer on itunesconnect so for you to get the Dsyms file you will have to

1. Go to itunes connect.
2. My Apps.
3. Select the specific app.
4. Navigate to testflight.
5. select the build you want to generate the Dsyms file for.
6. Click build meta data.
7. search for "includes symbols" and then click then click the download.

Then after downloading it run this code in your terminal replacing the quoted parts with the right file path.

```
/path/to/pods/directory/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols
 -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /path/to/dSYMs
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the current solution ! It seems that dsyms are now hidden away inside the TestFlight section - I wish Apple would make such things more obvious. I guess this would need to be done for every new release of the app ? Would never has figured that out without this answer.

Comment: I don't see the download button :(

Comment: @ericlong were you able to navigate to test flight and select the particular build you want to generate a Dsyms file for? If you have just use your browser search to look for "includes symbols" on the page, from there you should see a download button under this highlighted text.

Comment: @babatundeadewole Go to iTuneConnect -> Choose app -> TestFlight -> Select build -> Build Metadata 
Then I search for Includes Symbols, I saw "Yes" only, there is no download button.
Is there any condition elsewhere?

Comment: Seeing the same thing as @ericlong -- my app does not use Bitcode and I am not the agent, but I am an Admin in App Store Connect. Does these 2 facts affect the ability to download dSYMs from App Store Connect? And just to clarify, despite not using Bitcode and having used the google script to manually upload the dSYMs, I am still seeing the infamous red banner in Crashlytics.

Comment: @ettore where did you get stuck downloading the dSYM file or uploading it to firebase?

Comment: @babatundeadewole sorry, neither one. I just don't see the link to download the dSYMs from App Store Connect, I only see "Include symbols: yes" there. Uploading to Firebase succeeds using the script, but on Firebase I still see the red banner about missing dSYMs.

Comment: @ettore I am having the same issue, there's no download button. Where you able to find how to download the dSYM file or make the download option appear?

Comment: @buzali no, I have not. However the red banner did go away after updating the `run` and `upload-symbols` scripts with the most recent versions from https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/tree/master/Crashlytics -- then, per docs, I call `run` from the run-script build phase in my target, and from our CI we do also call `upload-symbols` explicitly ([per docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios#upload-dsyms))

Comment: Thanks @ettore! I ended up getting the dSYMs from the archive directly and uploading manually with `upload-symbols`.

Comment: Everyone should follow @Dipak answer, it's working...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the dynamic library is your project using cocoa pods or any other tool then Firebase needs Duplicate Symbol files to locate the faulty code in your library. If you want to read more about dSysms read this : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656391/whats-the-dsym-and-how-to-use-it-ios-sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656391/whats-the-dsym-and-how-to-use-it-ios-sdk)

To find dsysm folder, you first need the .ipa file on which crash was reported on your firebase. In your case, I suppose you are running on the simulator for testing. To get IPA follow these steps: [How to create ipa in xcode 6 without Apple Developer account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928721/how-to-create-ipa-in-xcode-6-without-apple-developer-account)

When you reach .iPA then right click and select show package contents, or follow this link: [iphone: Where the .dSYM file is located in crash report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088771/iphone-where-the-dsym-file-is-located-in-crash-report)

There you will find system folder. Upload this folder to firebase crashalytics.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So there is no way to have the build automatically upload the symbol files when we use CocoaPods?

Comment: Which folder should be upload? I can't find system folder

Answer (score 2):

I hope you have a resolved it till now. But for other who are using Firebase/Crashlytics. I uploaded the build and got crash but it was not showing in the console due to missing dsyms.

I logged into the itunes and goto the activity section. Then download the dsyms.[image]

After that I uploaded the dsyms to firebase console using below command:

```
/Users/ankitjaiswal/Code/oliobox-ios/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols
-gsp /Users/ankitjaiswal/Code/oliobox-ios/JacksonArtGallery/GoogleService-Info.plist
-p ios /Users/ankitjaiswal/Downloads/appDsyms.zip
```

But in this way you always manually need to download and upload it. This is not recommended instead you can follow this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports-new-sdk

Answer (score 2):

I have created Medium Story about dSYMs upload.

Stap by step how to upload with the terminal

Medium Link:
https://medium.com/@petarlemajic/firebase-dsyms-upload-1cf432c475f7
I will be happy if this helps somebody.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

**(October 21 - 2020)**

I was having a lot of trouble uploading my dsyms to firebase, this happend to me after i updated to FirebaseCrashlytics and removed my fabric SDK, before that i had no issues. I tried all solutions with no luck but finally figured out my problem after making a few changes in my code. It seems i had some conflicting values in my `info.plist` file and were not lining up with what was in my `GoogleService-Info.plist` file. The bundle ID in the `GoogleService-Info.plist` should be the same used as the url schemes within `info.plist`. After i made these changes i uploaded the DSYMs manually.

This is an example of how my bundle ids look in my project after updating:

`GoogleService-Info.plist`
[image]

`info.plist`
[image]

I then wanted this automated. I added the following script to the Build Phases > Run Script and i now have this automated as it was before when i was using the Fabric sdk. Just copy this code into run script, it should require no changes.

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

[image]

PS: Make sure you follow the other posts making sure you have "DWARF with dYSM file" set in build options as well.

Comment: Why does the key for BUNDLE_ID need to match that in the Info.plist URL schemes? That seems misleading. I can imagine it needs to match CFBundleIdentifier in the Info.plist.

Comment: @RicSantos, BUNDLE_ID is correct key name from GoogleService-Info.plist file, Please check again key in GoogleService-Info.plist file.

Answer is 100% correct.

Answer (score 2):

My appstore connect doesn't show any download dSYM link.
So, I followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39361649/13523399) instructions and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

After download dsym .zip file. You should run code below in Terminal.

```
/ProjectPath/Pods/Crashlytics/Crashlytics.framework/upload-symbols -gsp /ProjectPathForGoogleServiceFile/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /dSYMFilePath/dSYMs.zip
```

If upload-symbols command not found, you should update pods for Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Question is answered well already if you still want a ready-made script that you can copy and paste. Here you go.

```
    find

$HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode
/DerivedData/<target-name>-*/Build/Products/Develop-iphoneos

-name "*.dSYM" | xargs -I \{\}

$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols

-gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/<target-name>/GoogleService-Info.plist

-p ios \{\}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to firebase documents, instead of uploading `dsym` You can also provide your app's built `Info.plist` location to the build phase's Input Files field:

`$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)`

[They fixed bug and document updated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios&authuser=0#add-sdk)

Comment: but only works when bitcode-disabled

Answer (score 1):

If Bitcode enable = Yes

1. Go to App Store Connect
2. Go to iOS Build and Download dSYM
3. Open a terminal
4. Run the command

/Users/your-project-path/ios/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /Users/your-project-path/ios/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /Users/your-username/Downloads/appDsyms

5. Once you get the success message and refresh the Firebase console within some time you will see the reflections

Note: Upload all the built dSYM files to the Firebase

Answer (score 0):

Simple Steps Follow 1 Go to archive and right click on the latest version in which you want to get crash report on firebase 2 see the dsyms folder 3 create the Zip file of dsyms folder 4 finally upload that zip file into the firebase console

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is perfect and what I also followed. I would just like to add another way to download these dSyms.

Open Organizer from Xcode menu > Window > Organizer

Select the Application from left panel and select Archives tab.

Select the archive for the app release you want to download dSyms of. (If you have deleted archives, then you better follow the accepted answer)

On the right panel, click Download Debug Symbols. Now this will download those symbols into the archive itself. Simply right click the archive version > Show in Finder.

Here in finder, right-click archive > Show package contents.

This will open the contents to reveal the dSyms.

Now you don't need all of them, some of them will be your added frameworks/libs  from pods and other imports.

Select only the ones with alphanumeric labels.

[image]

You can zip these and upload to Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to developer.apple.com > Activity > iOS Build > Select Version > Download dSYM
2. Change **your-project-path** and **your-username**
3. Run this code on `Terminal`

   /Users/your-project-path/ios/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /Users/your-project-path/ios/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /Users/your-username/Downloads/appDsyms.zip
4. You'll see success message on the `Terminal`.
5. Check the crash logs on `Firebase Console` after 15-30 minutes.

[image: download symbold]

Comment: For me it has "Include Symbos: Yes", but no "Download dSYM" link.

Comment: @DielsonSales There could be no exceptions yet. Are you getting any not-found dSYM error on firebase console?

Comment: Yes, but mostly for older builds that I don't have the archive anymore. It's odd, if I try to download the symbols from Organizer it also says "No dSYMs were found for version x", but when I upload it it says explicitly there is debug symbols. But I usually don't send it with bitcode enabled, since the upload is too large and fails more often.

Answer (score 0):

The top solutions are good, thanks to their authors. Maybe this tips could help someone : when you want to test your configuration by crashing your app, build it with Xcode on the simulator, then stop the app and relaunch it directly in the simulator.
As the firebase doc says : The initial instance includes a debugger that interferes with Crashlytics. https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=ios#test_it_out

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me with React Native after I added Crashlytics. My app has "Includes Symbols" in TestFlight but no option to download dSyms.

Ultimately, There were 3 input files in the build phase that I had to add manually after comparing with the docs.

Make sure Xcode can automatically process dSYMs and upload the files:

[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?hl=en&authuser=0&platform=ios#check-input-files-setup)

After I added the 3 missing input files and rebuilt the app (and then uploaded to App Distribution via Github Actions), the error went away.