# Firebase Crashlytics data not showing on firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I have an application which I incorporated Crashlytics into it. I followed the docs but when I force a crash, Nothing shows up in my crash console. I checked the web for solutions but nothing seems to work.

.[image]

Comment: There is a delay till the crash shows up in the console. How long did you wait?

Comment: more than 12 hours.

Comment: run application without debugging

Comment: @SPatel I am currently running without debugging. Which was done in the Schema

Comment: I mean run app and stop it from Xcode and again run it directly from simulator

Comment: did that and still nothing shows up

Comment: I got this result in my firebase console `Upload 1 missing dSYM required to process 2 crashes`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Crashlytics: Upload missing dSYMs to see crashes from 1 versions.(iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296774/firebase-crashlytics-upload-missing-dsyms-to-see-crashes-from-1-versions-ios)

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35374388/608312