# Added Google Crashlytics in iOS - Does not connected to Firebase Crashlytics Dashboard

Tags: ios, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=2

I followed this link and the Firebase Analytics connected and showed events, but Firebase Crashlytics is not showing any crash, it isn't even able to connect to App.

And keeps showing the following image when clicked on Crashlytics in Left panel from Firebase Console.

[image]

This is a fresh project Firebase Crashlytics works fine with the earlier projects created using Fabric.

Comment: Have you built and run your app in the simulator? Before you can access the Crashlytics dashboard you need to build and run your app.

Comment: Its already Firebase is connected and showing events, but crashes are not shown on Crashlytics Dashboard

I have tried a fresh run it in Simulator and Device as well.

Comment: Any updates here? I'm having the same issue, but in Xcode console I can see that Crashlytics is installed correctly. I've also simulated crashes, redownload .plist, recreate iOS app in firebase. Nothing helped

Comment: @Jateko -  I didn't find any solution right away but I managed to get crash logs by creating a new app and initiating from 0, also I added Run script in the Build phase to upload dysm symbol.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by Adding Run Script as shown in Firebase, also I did a fresh start.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, following the Firebase docs did not work for me as I had to do a few additional things for the "Add the SDK" loading screen to disappear on the Firebase portal and show me the crashes.

In addition to what the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios) say, I did the following in addition to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64782202) which I have also outlined on a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66196122/1619193)

1. Go to Build Settings -> Debug Information Format -> Set all of them to DWARF with dSYM file
2. Go to Build Phases -> Add an additional run script and input the following

```
${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp ${PROJECT_DIR}/Your_path/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}
```

**Remember to replace {PROJECT_DIR} appropriately for your project**

3. Stage a crash in your application as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?authuser=0)
4. Disconnect your device / simulator from the debugger AKA launch it on your own rather than running it from XCode and then perform the crash
5. I was now able to see the above loading disappear and I could see my crash statistics instead