# FirebaseCrashlytics did not report crash to my firebase console dashboard

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, crash-reports, google-fabric

I was updating Fabric to new Firebase, my firebase showed old fabric crash report and no Firebase report. Now my firebaseCrashlytics version is 4.3.1. I had added GoogleService-Info.plist, script phase "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run" and phase's input files:${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME},
$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH).

When I run my app, xcode console printed "[Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 4.3.1", no other log. I did not know what problem happened.

Comment: If you getting this error & **Firebase Crashlytics: Upload missing dSYMs to see crashes from 1 versions.(iOS)** Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58762356/10150796 answer solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Few things you need to verify .

1- Is your crashlytics connected to your app.

Even though you initially connect your app in the setup phase to get the googleInfoPlist , you have to run it again and connect again .Select the crashlyitcs tab and you will get to click "Add SDK" which i think at this point you have completed .
After that run your app again and navigate through the app and at some point it will say that it is connected.

Another thing is you can force a crash but it wont appear in the crashlogs directly.

First you run it on the device and the stop running. Re-open the App and recreate the crash again. The Crash will not appear as long as the debugger is connected to your Emulator/Device