# iOS/Objective-C: How to import DWARF file in Firebase Crashlytics? "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" not working anymore

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, crashlytics, run-script

I just install Firebase, but impossible to import à DWARF file.
I put this line in my Script of the app, but it seems not to resolve the problem with a real device.

[image]
Script:

```
"${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run" -gsp  
"${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info/FormBoxRenaultExtensionDays/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios  
"${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}"
```

What do you think it is?

**EDIT:**
I tried to upload it in the console Firebase by compliling, archivinb, and downloading it in the xcode organizer with this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60056778/3581620) but it is still a problem, nothing happens, even by waiting 10 hours...
[image: image fake success]
It is saying success, but it is not resolving the problem at all...

Comment: Download the dSYM from AppStoreConnect

Comment: @Larme This is not an Apple Store application, it is internal in the entreprise...

Answer (score 1):

goto Window->organiser->archive->select build-> right click and show in finder than right click and show package content select the DYSM folder and compress it and upload it to firebase.

Comment: @ Shubham Tomar I already did it, but it doesn't resolve the problem. I update my ticket.

Answer (score 0):

To automate the dSYMs upload I usually check the following:

1. Make sure Xcode is generating dSYMs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios#check-xcode
2. Make sure Xcode is able to upload dSYMs automatically with the run script: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#set-up-dsym-uploading.
   This is the document related to CocoaPods: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods#product-specific-considerations

After doing this, to test this is working correctly:

1. Increase the version/build number (just to have a reference)
2. Do a small code change (This helps to trigger XCode into generating a new UUID and dSYMs)
3. Cause a new test crash to see if it shows up in the dashboard. That would confirm the SDK is working fine and that the dSYMs got uploaded.

If this is still failing, instead having this in the run script `"/Crashlytics/run"` you can have this command:

```
"${BUILD_DIR%/Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/upload-symbols" --build-phase --debug
```

The `--build-phase` argument makes the script to upload the dSYMs as part of the build process instead of doing it asynchronously, the caveat is that the build process could take longer.

The `--debug` argument makes the script print verbose output.

When building the app, you can see these logs in the build output. It can tell you if something went wrong. It also shows the appId it is sending the dSYMs, so it can help you see if it is uploading them to the right app.