# Firebase/Crashlytics - upload 1 dSYM file to process them. error why?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, dsym

Mine is Xcode 14.2 version and I have installed `Firebase/Crashlytics` pod successfully in project

then i add 2 crashes in code and run the code in simulator and hit that crashes in simulator and checked for crashes in **Firebase > Crashlytics > Dashboard**

then i got

> This app has 2 unprocessed crashes. Upload 1 dSYM file to process them.

1. then i found dSYM folder in  `press (right click) on archive -> Show In Finder -> Show Package Contents -> there is dSYMs folder` compressed that and browse in Firebase > Crashlytics > dSYMs tab then it is successfull

[image]

then after 1 hour still same error showing

2. so i have added `dSYMs` using script path in firebase commend line in terminal like this

> /Users/userName/Desktop/projectName/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /Users/userName/Desktop/projectName/projectName/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios /Users/userName/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2023-05-30/projectName\ 30-05-23,\ 7.12\ PM.xcarchive/dSYMs

this is also successfully
[image]

**if i run code and hit crash in device then crashes are showing in firebase but still `This app has 2 unprocessed crashes. Upload 1 dSYM file to process them.`   showing in firebase why? what else i need to do to fix this error** please guide me

[image] [image]

EDIT: its says required for 2.3(2) i have also added for 2.3(2) build

please find screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: Click on the dsym tab, it will tell you what version is missing. You likely have to upload more dsyms

Comment: @loremipsum, could you please once check my edit in post.. there its asking for `2.3(2)` so i have added also for 2.3(2)

Comment: @loremipsum, here what is Event Count. for optional it says count 3 and for required it says 2

Comment: If you loaded them and you have given it some time and you are still getting the message then they could be for 3rd parties. It used to be much easier to get all the dsyms from AppStore Connect. You might have to try until the crashes happen with a new version, try switching to SPM for Firebase and use the steps on the getting started to auto-load dsyms. I personally don't like cocoapods, ever since my switch to an M1 I avoid them every time I can.

Comment: @loremipsum, okay then i will switch to SPM and will give a try