# missing DSYMs to process crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics

I am not getting crash report mails and also no reports in crashlytics

In crashlytics, it is showing "It looks like we are missing dSYMs to process crashes for the versions below"

Actually, I have generated ipa file using "Development" distribution method.

Is this issue is because of generating ipa using "Development" distribution method ?

Please help me in resolving this, thanks in advance!

Comment: did you uploaded dsyms

Answer (score 3):

Here is steps to generate dsyms from xcode

**Step 1:**

Open Xcode and goto Windows --> Organizer

**Step 2:**

Select Build for which you want DSYMs and on right panel  Below Export and validate option 
 There is button **Download dSYMs**

And upload that to crashlytics to process the crash report

Hope it is helpful

Comment: @SureshVutukuru Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159244/xcode-there-are-no-dsyms-available-for-download

Comment: thanks, now i managed to get dsym file, but my doubt is why it is not automatically uploaded to crashlytics ? is it because that i have selected "Development" in distribution method ? how to make this automatic

Comment: I don't have much surety on that part As per my thinking we should upload it manually to there doesn't matter what build is i am not sure in this part

Comment: we should use "Adhoc" in distributing method while generating ipa, then only we will get reports (that is how it worked for me). My question was how to get crashlytics report not just how to get dSYMs. But thanks for your help, learnt something new

Answer (score 1):

in your Xcode project, under Build Phases add above run script:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```