# How do I upload/download dSYMs to App Store Connect (Testflight)?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, dsym

I was able to download dSYMs from App Store & TestFlight before:

[image]

I'm not sure what was changed in the project file, but in the next build, the button to download dSYMs is not there anymore:

[image]

I checked my project settings, and it looks like I do have dSYMs enabled. I'm not sure what else to change in my project settings to be able to download it from TestFlight again:

[image]

Comment: Check the git history of your project? There might be a clue there? Also, when archiving/uploading the app, did you checked/unchecked some things? There are there a few options concerning the dSyms

Comment: There is a discussion about this issue in apple dev forum but no solution was provided. Not yet. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/114655?page=2

Comment: Did you recently change the Enable Bitcode value?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the symbols are already properly loaded but you are not able to download them.

There is a discussion about this issue in apple dev forum but no solution was provided. Not yet. [developer.apple.com/forums/thread/114655?page=2](http://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/114655?page=2)

It could be an Apple side issue but in the meantime you can use the dSYMs files on your local build machine.

When the Bitcode is disabled no Apple side recompilation has performed so the correct symbols can be found on local machine used for the build.

Xcode->Window->Organizer->Archives

Right click your build -> show in finder

Right click Your xcarchive file -> Select "Show Package Contents"

you should be able to find here the dSYMs folder

Some people say that if you don't have bitcode enabled, Apple will merely show, "includes symbols: Yes" without the Download link.

Some others say that they have to use Xcode's Organiser and click the "Download dSYM" which didn't give an error, but apparently did nothing (no files appeared anywhere??), but then in iTunesConnect, the blue link appeared next to "Includes Symbols Yes".

[interesting discussion about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159244/xcode-there-are-no-dsyms-available-for-download)

About Crashlytics:  when building apps without bitcode, Crashlytics provides an upload-symbols tool that uploads your app’s dSYM local files every time that you need them for your app.
However, for apps with bitcode enabled, the process of uploading dSYMs isn’t so simple. Instead, you need to download updated dSYMs from Apple and upload them to Crashlytics each time you submit a new version of the app to App Store Connect.

Comment: Yes! We've updated the "Enable bitcode" from YES to NO because one of our dependencies has it turned off. I was researching how to turn on dysms, but I couldn't find the relationship of bitcode with dysms. I've already gone to "Show Package Contents" and uploaded dysms to crashlytics, but there are still some that are missing. I don't think this folder contains all dysms unlike testflight. That's why I'd like to bring the download button back in testflight.

Comment: If Bitcode is disabled then for sure the all the symbols related to your compilation are present in your local xarchive. Are you sure that you are uploading the right version of the symbols? Are you sure that you are uploading the dSYMs to Firebase in the proper way? Are you sure that the crash is not related to a precompiled library?

Comment: Just to let you know: Bitcode is strictly related to the symbols generation. if you enable bitcode then the only right symbols are present on Apple connect server and your local dSYMs are not so useful. On the other hand if bit code is disabled the local and the server side symbols should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

For all **Xcode 14** users: there is no need for that dSYM button since bitcode was deprecated in Xcode 14. Starting with Xcode 14, bitcode is no longer required for watchOS and tvOS applications, and the App Store no longer accepts bitcode submissions from Xcode 14.

[Download Xcode 13.4.1](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_13.4.1/Xcode_13.4.1.xip) (Link-Source: [[1](https://xcodereleases.com)]), update your project settings and upload again.

[Release notes:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode-Release-Notes/xcode-14-release-notes)

> **Deprecations**
> Starting with Xcode 14, bitcode is no longer required for watchOS and tvOS applications, and the App Store no longer accepts bitcode submissions from Xcode 14.
> Xcode no longer builds bitcode by default and generates a warning message if a project explicitly enables bitcode: “Building with bitcode is deprecated. Please update your project and/or target settings to disable bitcode.” The capability to build with bitcode will be removed in a future Xcode release. IPAs that contain bitcode will have the bitcode stripped before being submitted to the App Store. Debug symbols for past bitcode submissions remain available for download. (86118779)