# Crashlytics and Google Analytics and missing dSYM

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, crashlytics

Before i'm using Google Analytics on my app, the Crashlytics crash report working fine with no missing dSYM files warnings.
After I add Google Analytics on my app, the crash report is working but there are about 5 missing dSYM warnings shown in one version of my app.
And also I have check the UUIDs on archieved dSYM and there are no match UUIDs that shown on the missing dSYM warnings.

Please help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can upload dYSM manually in Crashlytics or Firebase

1. Open Xcode go to Organizer Option.
2. Select your last production release.
3. Right click on the archive and select "Show in Finder"
4. Right click on the .xcarchive shown in Finder and select "Show Package Contents"
5. Copy the "dSYMs" folder found inside
6. Compress the "dSYMs" folder and upload it to Crashlytics or Firebase

Comment: Hi, i am struggling to upload dsym on firebase. I can not find any option in firebase crashlytics for upload dsym files. Can you suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a workaround for this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35374388/2397068. You need to download the dSYM file from iTunes Connect--see that post for full details.

One possible explanation involves a change in the way apps with bitcode are handled by Apple.

I don't know if Google Analytics caused the problem; it may be a red herring in this case (it may be unrelated).