# Missing dSYMs in Crashlytics IOS

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, dsym

Hello I have been digging to find the solution but unfortunately I have not been able to find an answer. My issue is that I have my application that uses crashlytics. When pulling my crashlytics I see the Dsyms missing issue, i tried to add all the missing ones through the organizer but unfortunately i am not able to find all of them. please note my applications are not in the app store and I do not have itunes connect I am using an enterprise account. I noticed when running my application through the simulator and forcing a crash, Fabric will ask me for a new dSYM that I am not able to find. where can i find this dsym? I have verified through my build settings that I have dWARRF with dSYM enabled on both debug and release. If you have any ideas please let me know. Thank you!!

Comment: You can get it from iTunesConnect. It's been a while since I've had to get them from ITC, but IIRC, the downloaded file was a zip file with no extension...I spent more time than I care to admit to figure out they left the extension off...not sure if that's still the case. Once you get it from ITC, just upload it to Fabric.

Comment: @Adrian thank you for your comment, would this work even if the application is not on the app store?

Comment: Don't think so. Have a peek at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077722/crashlytics-were-missing-a-dsym-to-process-crashes

Comment: Hi, Paul from Crashlytics here. If you're still having difficulties, feel free to reach out: support(at)fabric(dot)io

Answer (score 1):

> If you’re using Xcode 10 on a new project, Xcode 10 adopts a new build
>   ordering that is independent of the ordered list in the Build Phases
>   of Xcode.
>
> Put **"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)"** into your
>   Fabric Run Script’s **“Input Files”** section to ensure your
>   installation of Fabric goes smoothly.

Reference to [Crashlytics documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/installation.html).

Comment: What if I have two info.plist files?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following (it works for me):

- Archive a binary of your target. Select your Scheme and make sure you have "Generic iOS Device": selected. Then in the Xcode menu, go to Window->Organizer and you will see your build
- Select the build. Check the date/time and version(build) numbers to ensure it is the one you want. Right-Click and select "Show in Finder"
- Right-click in the .xcarchive file and select "Show Package Contents"
- Look for the dSYMs directory. Right-click and compress.
- Move the dSYMs.zip file to your Desktop for easy uploading to Crashlytics.