# dSYM missing from Crashlytics Swift

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I'm implementing Firebase Crashlytics and after a bit of toggling I managed to get crashes reported to Firebase. The one thing is not working dough is dSYM . I tried documentation  guide but Firebase console is still asking for them.
I added another script apart from the Fabric one, containing this line`"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"`as documentation stated. But nothing.. Is there some extra steps that are not detailed in documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crashlytics: "We're missing a dSYM to process crashes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077722/crashlytics-were-missing-a-dsym-to-process-crashes)

Comment: @MikeBonnell thanks for pointing me to that post . I set Bitcode to No in both project and target but same results. Any suggestions?

Comment: Setting Bitcode to no will only help for future builds. Are you missing dSYMs for new builds (since changing the setting)?

Comment: @MikeBonnell I just noticed the the count of crashes with missing dSYMs doesn't increment. Is there a way to reset the reports and start fresh?

Comment: ok..I tried going back to wrong build settings as DWARF and took the second script out, to see if that started incrementing the missing dSYMs count again  but no, only total reports count still goes up. Is this making any sense ?

Comment: I also zipped dSYM file and uploaded it manually from console but is still asking for a dSYM with a specific UUID..

Comment: @MikeBonnell , following a comment of yours in a post found out that the UUID for the latest generated dSYM  is not the same of the one that Firebase is missing. Hence, now it's all working and I'm left with a missing dSYM of when things weren't set properly right? Is there any way to get it removed?

Comment: It will be removed automatically, I think after 7 days.

Comment: Great ! Thank you very much!